# how to accurately estimate the size of all pages + images in a blog or forum

Tags: search, lucene, indexing

I plan to create a custom search engine powered by Lucene, is there some software/tool/method to accurately determine the size of the index for an entire blog or forum site?

Comment: Best way would be indexing some portions of that site and making a projection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As L.B says- the best way is to index some portions of that site and accordingly make a projection.